# Unfilled form inputs act like filled on processing PHP page

Tags: php, html, forms, isset

I'm running a very simple HTML page with form in it. I send data through POST method and process them on a PHP page. I've made a simple if statement to check if all inputs have been filled. If not, return is false.

Problem is that when some inputs are not filled, those fields then act like filled on PHP page and if statement return TRUE and PAGE continue processing. What I've done wrong?

HTML:

```
<form class="add_content grid_12 alpha" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    method="POST" action="add_content_2.php" name="excersise_upload">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="excersise_name">Název cviku:</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="excersise_name" id="excersise_name">
        </li> 

        <li>
          <label for="selected_part">Partie cviku:</label><br />
          <select name="selected_part" id="selected_part">
          <?php
            get_parts();
          ?>
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="selected_difficulty">Vyber obtížnost cviku:</label>
          <br />
          <select name="selected_difficulty" id="selected_difficulty">
            <option value="1">začátečník</option>
            <option value="2">mírně pokročilý</option>
            <option value="3">pokročilý</option>  
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="excersise_info">Popis cviku:</label><br />
          <textarea name="excersise_info" id="excersise_info"></textarea>              
        </li>

        <li>
          <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
          <input type="file" name="excersise_image" accept="image/jpeg">
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="image_name">Název obrázku:</label><br />
          <input type="text" name="image_name" id="image_name">
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="submit" value="Přidat do databáze">
        </li>
      </ul>            
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
if ((isset($_POST['excersise_name'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['selected_part'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['selected_difficulty'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['excersise_info'])) &&
        (isset($_FILES['excersise_image'])) &&
        //(isset($_FILES['image_name'])) &&
        $_FILES['excersise_image']['size'] > 0) {.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below `if` condition in PHP:

```
 if((isset($_POST['excersise_name']) && !empty($_POST['excersise_name'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['selected_part']) && !empty($_POST['selected_part'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['selected_difficulty']) && !empty($_POST['selected_difficulty'])) &&
    (isset($_POST['excersise_info']) && !empty($_POST['excersise_info'])) &&
    (isset($_FILES['excersise_image']) && !empty($_FILES['excersise_image'])) &&
    //(isset($_FILES['image_name'])) &&
    $_FILES['excersise_image']['size'] > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `if( ! empty($_POST['excersise_name'])  && ...)` instead of `isset()` to check the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var_dump($_POST['field_name'])`; to check what comes if the fields is submitted as empty.
And add a checking in your if ststement like `trim($_POST['field_name'])` to cut if spaces comes when the form is submitted like

```
 if(trim($_POST['field_name'])!=''){
    //Proced
 }
 else{
  //Do not proced
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset` checks to see if the thing exists, not if it is empty or not. I use a combination of `isset` and `!= ''` to check if it's set, AND it's not empty. e.g.

```
if ((isset($_POST['myThing'])) and (trim($_POST['myThing']) != ''))
{
    // Ready to go
}
```